# Why does it take a really long time to connect python kernel in VScode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I try to run .ipynb in the VScode, but it takes a long time to connect the kernel & there is no error message. I wonder how to solve it?

I tried to restart the VScode several times but it didn't help. Last week I could connect the kernel but now it doesn't work.

Comment: does it work with running python from the command line

Comment: Could you please paste the output into the article?  (Jupyter: Show output)